# jtable returns only one row from the database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i want the table to return the data from database without specifying the number of rows, i used the autoincrement in the  default tablemodel but it doesnnot display all the rows, i have to define the table outside the actionlistener so as to add it to a JPanel,so  the problem is my table returns only one row fro the database

```
int row = 1;
     Object [] colnames = {"year","term","balance"};
     JTable table4 = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(colnames,++row));
     JScrollPane pane  = new JScrollPane(table4);





 saachs.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String adm = adms.getText();
             int row = 0;

            Connection con = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception ("driver not found");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
              try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"abda","abda");
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }if(con!=null){
                Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                String query = "select a.year,a.term,a.payable - b.total_paid balance from seet a join ( select adm, extract(year from date) tyear,class, term, sum(paid) total_paid from fees group by adm,class,term) b on a.class = b.class and b.adm = '"+adms.getText()+"' and a.term = b.term and a.year = b.tyear";

                try {
                    st = con.createStatement();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    while(rs.next()){
                        table4.setValueAt(rs.getString(1),row,0);
                        table4.setValueAt(rs.getString(2),row,1);
                        table4.setValueAt(rs.getString(3),row,2);

                        row++;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't directly set your JTable's values with the `setValueAt(...)` method but instead create a DefaultTableModel object within your `actionPerformed(...)` method, and inside your `while (rs.next())` method create a new `Vector<String>` that you fill with the data from the current row of the ResultSet, and at the end of the while loop, pass this Vector into your model by calling its `addRow(Vector v)` method. Then pass this model into the JTable by calling the table's `setModel(TableModel model)` method.

Something like:

```
   try {
      Object[] columnNames = { "year", "term", "balance" };
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
      while (rs.next()) {
         Vector<String> rowData = new Vector<>();
         rowData.add(rs.getString(1));
         rowData.add(rs.getString(2));
         rowData.add(rs.getString(3));
         row++;
         model.addRow(rowData);
      }
      table4.setModel(model);
   } catch (SQLException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Warning: code has not beentested

Comment: am new to the site....i neva knew there are such rules..anywei..got it..though i have no enough reputation to thumb it up